# A nice and simple free HTTPS server component for .NET?

Tags: .net, https

Asking for recommendations. I want an object on which I can specify a port to listen to, provide the server keys somehow, leave accepting connections, and preferably provide some helpers for parsing HTTP headers, and construct HTTP responses. No need to handle the request/response bodies, I can deal with opaque blobs.

Oh, and a .NET HTTPS client would be fine too.

...OK, OK, I'm accepting suggestions of non-free solutions too. But open-source is preferred.

Comment: Lots of classes in .NET for client and server HTTP and SSL. I wouldn't be surprised if you can put these together. `System.Net.WebClient` should work just fine with an HTTPS url for example.

Comment: This question was a #1 hit on Google for me when searching for .Net http server.  For anyone looking for this, I suggest Ceen Httpd.  Ceen is mature and strikes a good balance between features and lightweight. It boasts high performance in low resource environments.  Here's the Github repo: https://github.com/kenkendk/ceenhttpd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can roll your own quite easily:

[System.Net.HttpListener Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx)
[HttpListener basics](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2007/02/22/httplistener-for-dummies-a-simple-http-request-reflector.aspx)
[Modifying for https](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adarshk/archive/2004/11/10/255467.aspx)(Note article is dated when this class was introduced)

Comment: The HTTPS instructions are Windows-only. Any way of making HttpListener work with HTTPS in Linux?

Comment: I couldn't gather by your question that you were targeting Linux, I'm not familiar with mono, but it may be possible - this thread seems to think it works well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923966/does-httplistener-work-well-on-mono

Comment: Noob, HTTP works out of the box in HttpListener + Mono + Linux, my problem is now HTTPS. I'm targeting both platforms.

Answer (score 2):

My webserver supports SSL, MVC, Digest authentication and other stuff:

http://webserver.codeplex.com

As for the .Net httplistener, you need administrator privileges to be able to configure it.

**Update:**

My new library has a faster HttpListener: https://github.com/jgauffin/Griffin.Framework/

Answer (score -2):

This Wikipedia article lists many lightweight HTTP servers. Hope it helps.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_lightweight_web_servers

Comment: Which of these do you suggest using in a .NET application?

Comment: Sorry, I should of been more specific. Use this Wiki link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_HTTP_server