# how to run a RESTful webservice over service stack on an https (ssl) channel

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, rest, servicestack

I looked at the documentation and examples in the [service stack](http://www.servicestack.net/) library and googled around but couldn't find a way to create an ssl (https) web service.
In particular in the example i run the console example (really cool) that extends the AppHostHttpListenerBase class. I would like to make it run with https.

Answer (score 11):

You must set up a Server Certificate for the Http Listener, here's a walk through example of how to do that:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jpsanders/how-to-walkthrough-using-httplistener-or-http-server-unmanaged-code-c-as-an-ssl-simple-server

Whilst here is an article for setting up SSL with HttpListener on Mono:
[Does HttpListener work well on Mono?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923966/does-httplistener-work-well-on-mono)

Comment: thanks! this is actually the solution to my question. but what about mono? how you can do the same on a linux server running mono?

Comment: @gigi I've updated my answer to show a link for Mono's HttpListener, hope it helps.