# ServiceStack : BasicAuth and Security

Tags: authentication, servicestack

I would like to authenticate user trying to use my SS web services. I found the sample code and followed PLURALSIGHT tutorial but I was wondering if user/password used during first connection is encrypted or something on the network?

At this time we used to secure our WCF with certificates but THAT'S A REAL PAIN! and at the same time passing user/password on each WS is a security failure.

How does SS manage security of authentications parameters? Can I use it like that without worrying about possible security failure?

Comment: Are 'user' & 'pwd' visible using network analyzers ?

Answer (score 2):

Credentials will be sent plain text and it is expected that you configure SSL for the authentication traffic.

Comment: Any idea how to easily put this in place ? 
i am new to SSL

Answer (score 2):

[ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net) is just a standard ASP.NET or HttpListener web application. The standard way to encrypt HTTP traffic in any Web Application is to call your services over https. HTTPS is enabled/configured outside of your ServiceStack service (i.e. Web Application layer) so ServiceStack itself doesn't require any special attention when enabling SSL.

Setting up HTTPS on ServiceStack is the same as any other IIS/ASP.NET or HttpListener application. In both cases HTTPS is a [transport layer security (TLS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) protocol that is enabled at the WebServer/Host level (e.g. IIS) and **not** in your web application (e.g. ServiceStack). So when seeking how to enable SSL you should be looking on how to enable it at the WebServer host level, e.g. IIS, Nginx, HttpListener, etc (and not ServiceStack).

E.g. If you've got ServiceStack hosted in an ASP.NET Host, than a simple search for [IIS SSL on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=iis%20ssl&oq=iis%20ssl&aqs=chrome.0.57j60j64l2j62l2.1485&sugexp=chrome,mod=3&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) will provide plenty of instructions and walk throughs [like this one](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis). If you've got ServiceStack hosted in a self-hosted HTTP Listener, [see this answer instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8280413/85785).

Answer (score 0):

If your service is being consumed in an Enterprise environment and if you have AD, you can consider using WSHttpSecurity binding with binding configuration set to use Windows Credentials. This can eliminate the use of certificate. If your service is cross-enterprise and you dont have AD, you will have to do certificates

If you are doing Windows credential type, here's a sample config

```
<security mode="Transport">
   <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
</security>
```